# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 813, 701, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, tf.keras

I'm having some trouble getting a SimpleRNN to run. I'm attempting to create a image classifier RNN using Keras using tensorflow. I read the images using the Keras ImageDataGenerator FlowFromDirectory method so I can control the batch size through it and passing my training set as my x value in the fit method. I believe my issue is with the input_shape parameter of the SimpleRNN layer. I understand it should be (batch size, time steps, input dimension) but I can't understand why the array that is given to the layer is (32, 813, 701, 3). Below is my current code.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../main_set2/train_set',
                                                 target_size=(813, 701),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('../main_set2/test_set',
                                            target_size=(813, 701),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            class_mode='binary')
timesteps = 20

model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32,
                    activation='tanh',
                    use_bias=True,
                    kernel_initializer='orthogonal',
                    recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                    input_shape=(timesteps, 1)
                    ))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_set, 
          epochs=50, 
          verbose=2, 
          validation_data=test_set,
          steps_per_epoch=50, 
          validation_steps=20)
```

I'd like to understand what input_shape expects and what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: your image is a color image with three channels. you are using `batch_size` of 32. `target_size` is specified to be `(813, 701)`, thereby you get the shape `(32, 813, 701, 3)`

Comment: also an RNN layer expects 3-dimensional input and hence the error. The three dimensions are `(batch_size, time_steps, input_dimension)`. In you code, you have specified `input_shape` to be `(20, 1)` which is not right because while loading you set timesteps to be `813` and in the call you set it to be `20`

Comment: @learner Sorry I forgot to add the fit method before. As you can see on it now I'm passing the training set as a generator there so I believe that is where the (813,701) is coming from. Any idea what I should change here to get the RNN layer running passing the images as a generator like I'm doing so.